# Inserting element into array containing a queue of structs

Tags: c, compiler-errors, arguments, function-call, incompatibletypeerror

I have an array that contains a pointer to a queue, the queue contains structs, I'm not sure what the problem is here but it's at `InsertionDecroissant` right before the return.

Compiling problem:

```
dem.c: In function ‘InsertionDecroissant’:
dem.c:240:36: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘InsertionDecroissant’
  f.t->suiv=InsertionDecroissant(f.t->suiv,d,pts); // if none of those conditions work, recall the same function but with the next element in queue.
                                 ~~~^~~~~~
dem.c:228:32: note: expected ‘File’ {aka ‘struct <anonymous>’} but argument is of type ‘struct maillon *’
 File InsertionDecroissant(File f,DemLogement d,int pts)
                       ~~~~~^
```

Code:

```
    typedef struct
    {
        int     handicape;
        int     violenceCouple;
        int     hebergTemp;
        int     pasDeLogement;
        int     logDangereux;
    } Point;
    
    typedef struct
    {
        Point       points;
        char        nomDem[30];
        char        prenomDem[30];
        int         nbrDemandeur;
        int         ressourcesAnnu;
    } DemLogement;
    
            typedef struct maillon {
                DemLogement d;
                int pt;
                struct maillon *suiv;
            } Maillon;
            
            typedef struct {
                Maillon *t;
                Maillon *q;
            } File;
            
            
            void TraitementDem(DemLogement *tdem,int nbDem)
            {
                File tab[6];
                int type,pts;

                for (int i = 0; i < nbDem; ++i)
                {
                    type = TypeLogement(tdem[i].nbrDemandeur); // gets the type of house the applicant needs.
                    pts = atribPoint(tdem[i]); // calculates the total amount of points the applicant can have
                    tab[type] = InsertionDecroissant(tab[type],tdem[i],pts);
                }
            }
            
            File InsertionDecroissant(File f, DemLogement d, int pts)
            {
                if(vide(f)) // if queue is empty
                {
                    f=filenouv(); // Creates new queue
                    return adjq(f,d,pts); // Inserts struct at the beggining of the queue (d) is the struct.
                }
            
                if(pts>=f.t->pt) // if the value passed by the parent func is > or equals the value inside the queue
                    return adjq(f,d,pts);// Inserts struct at the beggining of the queue (d) is the struct.
            
                f.t->suiv=InsertionDecroissant(f.t->suiv,d,pts); // if none of those conditions work, recall the same function but with the next element in queue.
                return f;
            
            }
        File adjq(File f, DemLogement x,int pts) // adds element to queue
        {
            Maillon *m;
            m=(Maillon *)malloc(sizeof(Maillon));
            if(m==NULL)
                {printf("Probleme malloc files.\n");exit(1);}
            m->d=x;
            m->pt=pts;
            m->suiv=NULL;
            if(vide(f))
            {
                f.t=m;
                f.q=m;
                return f;
            }
            f.q->suiv=m;
            f.q=m;
            return f;
        }
File filenouv(void)
{
    File f;
    f.t=NULL;
    f.q=NULL;
    return f;
}

bool vide(File f)
{
    if(f.t==NULL)
        return true;
    return false;
}
int TypeLogement(int nbr)
{
    if(nbr==1 || nbr==2)
        return 0;
    if(nbr==3)
        return 1;
    if(nbr==4)
        return 2;
    if(nbr==5)
        return 3;
    if(nbr==6)
        return 4;
    if(nbr>7)
        return 5;
}

int atribPoint(DemLogement d)
{
    int total;
    total = d.points.handicape * 30 + d.points.violenceCouple * 15 + d.points.hebergTemp * 15 + d.points.pasDeLogement * 10 + d.points.logDangereux  * 8;
    return total;
}
```

Comment: What is `filenouv`? Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InsertionDecroissant` expects a list (`File`) for the first argument, but receives a node (`struct maillon`) in the recursive call.

Get rid of the needless recursion. Instead, use a loop that finds the pointer to modify.

```c
// Type-safe version of malloc.
#define MALLOC(T, n) ((T*)malloc(sizeof(T) * n))

// Return 0 on success.
// Returns -1 and sets `errno` on error.
int InsertionDecroissant( File *f, DemLogement d, int pt ) {
   // Un pointeur au pointeur que l'on veut modifier.
   Maillon *suivant_ptr = &( f->t );

   // On trouve où insérer.
   while ( *suivant_ptr && pt > (*suivant_ptr)->pt )
      suivant_ptr = &( (*suivant_ptr)->suivant );

   // On crée un nouveau maillon.
   Maillon *nouveau = MALLOC( Maillon, 1 );
   if ( !nouveau )
      return -1;

   nouveau->d       = d;
   nouveau->pt      = pt;
   nouveau->suivant = *suivant_ptr;

   // On insère le nouveau maillon.
   *suivant_ptr = nouveau;

   // On ajuste la queue si nécessaire.
   if ( !nouveau->suivant )
      f->q = nouveau;

   return 0;
}
```

The caller would look something like this:

```c
if ( InsertionDecroissant( &tab[type], d, pt ) == -1 ) {
   perror("Can't insert node");
   exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `while ( !*suivant_ptr` be `while ( *suivant_ptr`?

Answer (score 0):

> error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘InsertionDecroissant’

This error message means that you are using the first argument of an incorrect type other than it is expected by the function for the first parameter.

For example in this statement where there is present a function call

```
f.t->suiv=InsertionDecroissant(f.t->suiv,d,pts);
```

the first argument expression `f.t->suiv` does not have the expected type  for the first parameter of the function `InsertionDecroissant`.
Instead if an expression of the type `File` the expression have the type `struct maillon *` due to this declaration

```
typedef struct maillon{
    DemLogement d;
    int pt;
    struct maillon *suiv;
}Maillon;
```